# CakePHP Validate Masked Credit Card With Regex

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, credit-card

I am creating an update billing information section for my users. I am currently passing a masked credit card number to the form. I do not want the user to have to update their credit card information if they only want to update say their billing address.

I am attempting to use regex to match the masked credit card, but I have not been able to get ANY regex patterns to match... Even 100% wildcards...

Here are couple of examples of what I have tried...

================================================================

The Masked Credit Card Value Is XXXXXXXXXXXX0012

================================================================

```
'creditcard' => array(
         'creditcard' => array(
            'rule' => array('cc', 'all', false, '^[.]+$'),
            'message' => 'Required',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
            ),
    ),
```

================================================================

```
    'creditcard' => array(
        'creditcard' => array(
            'rule' => array('cc', 'all', false, '/^[X]+[0-9](4,)$/'),
            'message' => 'Required',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
            ),
    ),
```

================================================================

```
    'creditcard' => array(
        'creditcard' => array(
            'rule' => array('cc', 'all', false, '/^[x]+[0-9]+$/i'),
            'message' => 'Required',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
            ),
    ),
```

Any Ideas Are Greatly Appreciated!

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete answer but in your first example, a period inside [ ] actually matches the character . not anything. So if you change that one to:

```
/^.+$/
```

it will probably work better.

In the second example you should use curly braces { } instead of parenthesis to designate length. Like so:

```
/^[X]+[0-9]{4,}$/
```

The last one looks good though. But by fixing the first two you might get started on finding the source of the problem at least!

Comment: and the first one missing the `/` before and after, should be `/^.*$/`

Comment: Indeed! Added them to my answer.

Comment: /^[X]+[0-9]{4,}$/ works, turns out, one of the developers on my team had overridden the validate, from the model, in the controller, thank you so much for your help! =]

Answer (score 0):

The `^` and `$` match the beginning and end, respectively, of the whole string, not just of individual lines.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see why you need regex for this, unless I'm missing something.

Perhaps one way to do this would be to output the masked card number as just plain text, and provide a text box for the new card number.

When the form is submit, if this field is empty, then just `unset` the array key before saving, so the existing card value remains untouched.

If there is a new number, you can update as needed.

Comment: "Perhaps one way to do this would be to output the masked card number as just plain text, and provide a text box for the new card number. " Thats good thinking outside the box! =] Thank You!